# Validate Strings to be of a exact "kind" (java)

Tags: java, string, validation

My problem is that I cant make my string a valid one,

The valid way is this:

for example ---> "DP 3#4" this is a rule for a game, and i must validate it... I searched for tokenizer, and even saving an array of char type, but after getting the chars in the array, i just can't work with it the way i want to.

Comment: can you post a code example of what you are trying to do with this 'DP 3#4' string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (though not all) patterns like this can be easily checked using a Regular Expression. Take some time to [learn how to build a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) that will be valid only for the valid pattern you're looking for. Then you should be able to use code [like in these examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) to check input against that pattern.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to learn this to see if it can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The question was vague so I gave an appropriately general answer. The link was merely to point the OP to a reputable source at the time of asking. Of course, regex can be easily Googled and learned elsewhere if the link died. I think the concern addressed by the rule is applicable if the answer is contained in the linked page, not if the links are merely references.

Comment: During review I marked this as a "link-only answer" (which it pretty much is) and when that happens, an automated comment gets added to the post; I didn't write the comment myself.